# How to prove revised Fatou's Lemma?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

It is the problem from Durret Exercise 3.24

Let $g\geq 0$ be continuous. If $X_n \Rightarrow X_{\infty}$ (convergent in distribution), then $\liminf E(g(X_n))\geq E(g(X_\infty))$

Suppose we have know the  theorm:
1. Fatou's lemma: If $f_n \geq 0$, then
$\liminf \int f_n \, d\mu \geq \int \liminf f_n \, d\mu$

Solution：
$X_n \Rightarrow X_{\infty}$, $\exists Y_n \stackrel d= X_n$, $ Y \stackrel d= X_{\infty}$ s.t, $Y_n \stackrel{a.s}{\longrightarrow} Y$

Thus we have $g(Y_n) \stackrel{a.s}{\longrightarrow} g(Y)$ with $g()\geq 0$

Thus according to Fatou's lemma,
$\liminf E(g(Y_n))\geq E(g(Y))$

My question:
How to prove $\liminf E(g(X_n))\geq E(g(X_\infty))$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $X \stackrel d= Y$ and $g$ is continuous, then $$E[g(X)] = E[g(Y)]$$ provided at least one side makes sense (i.e. at least one of $E[g(X)^+]$ or $E[g(X)^-]$ is finite)

In your case, $g \geq 0$ implies $g(X)^- = 0$ for any random variable $X,$ so...